# Angular 2 remove true/false value in input

Tags: javascript, angular

Is there a quick solution to remove the `true/false` value in the `input` box when user tick the checkbox so it would show the default `placeholder` instead of the value `true/false`.

hoping it can be done using`inline` code with the `input` field, the idea is just to hide/show the text but when the `checkbox` is `true` it puts that value in the input box

see the example:
https://plnkr.co/edit/TWnTY3oXYGlcSSIJFGqi?p=preview

Comment: then what your check box gonna do?

Comment: well basically just to hide/show the text, but every time the checkbox is true it puts that value in the input.

Comment: so its to hide/show the input value not the out text with "Hello ....."

Comment: Sorry yeah that's what I meant, the text, but it can be changed later but it'd be the same purpose.

Comment: Did you try adding a `reset()` method to your controller that sets ngModel to sth. like undefined? When the checkbox sets the value in ngModel it will most likely be true or false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo can try changing the model for check box To something else like "checked"

```
<label>Name:</label>
 <!-- data-bind to the input element; store value in yourName -->
 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" placeholder="Enter a name here">
      <hr>
    <!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
  <h1 [hidden]="!checked || !yourName|| checked==null ">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

You can check this plank [Plank](https://plnkr.co/edit/CnBjI7OnAIgORi0f6y5A?p=preview)

Comment: can the logic be applied if your input is in `ngFor`? but instead of hiding the text, it would be the input.

Comment: can you please elaborate with some example

Comment: let just say you have multiple inputs with dynamic `ngModel` which is coming from a json (e.g name), and then the checkbox should be relative to that input field so it hides the input that is bind with the checkbox.  `<input type="text" id="{{x.name}}" [(ngModel)]="{{ x.name }}">` input would look like this.

Comment: You can do something like this - https://plnkr.co/edit/a3xZ1ULHdZnOrU6XEXhT?p=preview

In this case i made input box readonly until the checkbox is not checked . So you can use this.

Comment: Yeah but its better to hide it than disabling or readonly, its like `show more` in a way.

Comment: you can do that by directive or by jQuery .  its better to make it disable because after checking the check box ,the value will be visible

Comment: Yeah but if you have 10 or more inputs it will take up space, and if more of optional inputs so only show it if you need it kind of thing.

Comment: so for that you should go for directive .   and if my answer is good for you . you can accept the answer . thanks .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126036/discussion-between-viplock-and-ncore).

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

Html

```
<label>Name:</label>
<!-- data-bind to the input element; store value in yourName -->
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="reset" placeholder="Enter a name here" (click)="removeModelValue()">
<hr>
<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
<h1 [hidden]="!reset">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

ts

```
export class HelloWorld {
  // Declaring the variable for binding with initial value
  yourName: string = '';
  reset: boolean = true;
  removeModelValue() {
     this.yourName = '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Your Code as below:

**HTML:**

```
<label>Name:</label>
<!-- data-bind to the input element; store value in yourName -->
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="yourName" (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)"  placeholder="Enter a name here">
<input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked" placeholder="Enter a name here">
<hr>
<!-- conditionally display `yourName` -->
<h1 [hidden]="isChecked==false || isChecked==null">Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
```

**Component(ts)**

```
export class HelloWorld {
  isChecked:boolean=false;
  // Declaring the variable for binding with initial value
  yourName: string = '';

  valuechange(newValue) {
    mymodel = newValue;
    if(mymodel!='')
    {
      this.isChecked=true;
    }
    else
    {
      this.isChecked=false;
    }
  }
}
```